# Why is my bash script blocking?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script : `my.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

do_sth()
{
    sleep 5
}

main()
{
    do_sth >/dev/null &
    echo do sth in background ...
}

if [ "$1" = "1st_way" ]; then
    main
elif [ "$1" = "2nd_way" ]; then
    main >/dev/null
fi
```

The following command returns immediately

```
./my.sh 1st_way | cat
```

But, the following command blocks for 5 seconds

```
./my.sh 2nd_way | cat
```

I wonder why it is blocking for 5 seconds in the 2nd way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

main() {
    cd /tmp
}

main > /dev/null
echo goodbye
```

Before bash runs the `main` function, it needs to redirect its own standard output to `/dev/null`. Then it needs to run the `main` function. Then, before executing the `echo` command, it needs to restore its standard output to whatever it was before the redirect.

Here's how it does that. To do the redirect, it opens `/dev/null`, getting (let's say) file descriptor 3. Then it duplicates its file descriptor 1 (standard output) to the first available fd ≥ 10, getting (let's say) 10. Then it duplicates fd 3 (open on `/dev/null`) to fd 1, and closes fd 3.

Later, to undo the redirect, it duplicates fd 10 (open on bash's original standard output) onto fd 1, and closes fd 10.

Okay, now back to your script. All the same things happen when your script says `main >/dev/null`, so while `main` is executing, fd 10 is open on the shell's original standard output, which is the writable end of the pipe to `cat`.

When your `main` says `do_sth >/dev/null &`, the shell forks. The child shell inherits fd 10, so both the parent and child shells have fd 10 open on the pipe. (Note that the shell knows that it doesn't need to save its standard output here because of the `&` making it fork.)

When the child shell, in `do_sth`, runs `sleep`, it forks to run `sleep` and waits for `sleep` to exit. So the child shell hangs around for five seconds, and during that time it has fd 10 open on the writable end of the pipe.

The `cat` process doesn't read EOF on the readable end of the pipe until all file descriptors on the writable end are closed, which doesn't happen until that child shell exits, which doesn't happen until `sleep` exits.